# Errors in do catch statement in swift

Tags: json, swift, try-catch

I'm trying to explore this new (for me) language, and I'm making an app that like many others retrieve some json data from a server.
in this function (from a tutorial I found) I get 4 errors, and I'm unable to fix it:

```
 func json_parseData(data: NSData) -> NSDictionary? {
    do {
    let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
    print("[JSON] OK!")
    return (json as? NSDictionary)
    }catch _ {
        print("[ERROR] An error has happened with parsing of json data")
        return nil

    }
}
```

the first one is at the "try", xcode suggest me to fix it using "try;"
the others at the "catch" and are this others:

- Braced block of statement is an unused closure
- Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
- Expected while in do-while-loop

please help me to understand

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using swift 2.0 right?

Comment: You're using Xcode 6, but Swift 2 is only available in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using Xcode 6.x and Swift 1.x where the `do-try-catch` syntax is not available (only Xcode 7 and Swift 2)

This code has equivalent behavior:

```
func json_parseData(data: NSData) -> NSDictionary? {
    var error: NSError?

    // passing the error as inout parameter
    // so it can be mutated inside the function (like a pointer reference)
    let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainerserror: &error)

    if error == nil {
        print("[JSON] OK!")
        return (json as? NSDictionary)
    }
    print("[ERROR] An error has happened with parsing of json data")
    return nil
}
```

Note: as of Xcode 7 beta 6 you can also use `try?` which returns `nil` if an error occurs.